# disable items during specific hours of the day php

Tags: php, mysql, time, restrictions

I have a site that is based on requests, users can request items,  I want to restrict some of the requests during certain hours of the day.

For example the user can request `item5` only between say 5pm and 8pm. The rest of the time it's unavailable.

My site is in PHP with a MySQL backend.

Ideally, I would love a function I could call with an item id, the function would check time values from the database and return a true or false value.

It would be much appreciated if someone has some example code, I've tried reading up on time in PHP but its fried my head.

Comment: What do you have so far? What is the structure of your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pop in a startTime and endTime field intot he database using a time() datatype. Into these fields, enter the time they are available from and when they have to be back.

Then, it is a simple matter for a query to get the available items back.

```
tableAvailability
|--------------------------------|
| id     | availStart | availEnd |
|--------------------------------|
| 1      | 15:00:00   | 18:00:00 |
| 2      | 12:00:00   | 12:30:00 |
|--------------------------------|


$startTime='15:30:00';
$requiredTime=2; // Showing Hours for example

$sql="
select
    id
from
    tableAvailability
where
    ".$startTime." >= availStart
    and addTime('".$startTime."', '".$requiredTime.":00:00')<availEnd";
```

Comment: i basically have done this, and seems to work, do you know what the best way is to convert to gmt? using the time format i have of  $now = date('H:i:s');  thanks

Comment: If your users are going to be spread out along different timezones, get them to enter in their local timezone and modify for that. You can also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php to set the timezone that is calculated by PHP, or configure it in the php.ini file.

Comment: i set the timezone in php and just worked it from that, the code will only be executed from one internal location so this was sufficient thanks

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the database has two columns in the item table called `available_start` and `available_end`. Both of these are assumed to be DATETIME.

```
function isItemAvailableNow(item_id){
    # Globals are bad but this gets the point across
    global $db;

    # Get the item from the database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = " . mysql_real_escape_string(item_id, $db) . ";");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    # Pull the beginning and ending availablity time out of the database result
    $available_start = $row['available_start']
    $available_end   = $row['available_end']

    # Get the current time in the same format as the MySQL DATETIME type
    $now = date('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');

    return ($now >= $available_start) && ($now <= $available_end);
}
```

This code has not been tested and I have made a few assumptions (like you're using MySQL) but this should get you started.

You'll also want to consider timezones but that's another discussion.

Answer (score 1):

`time()`, `date()`, and maybe `mktime()` is what you need. Simply compare time at the moment  with time range that you allow/disallow viewing content

[PHP date() manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - this is really a powerful function

there is also a timezone issue, that you might consider